# Emacs on Mac OS X Lion forward delete

Tags: macos, emacs, osx-lion

I updated my iMac desktop from Snow Leopard to Lion. I use an extended USB keyboard which has two delete keys: one together with the usual keys (above \) and one in the extended part (below fn).

In my Emacs under Snow, the first delete key worked as "backward delete" and the second one as "forward delete". However under Lion, they are both "backward delete".  On the other hand, they work as expected in other contexts (TextEditor, MS Word, Terminal, this text, etc).

I presume I have to insert some additional key configuration in my .emacs file, but I don't know what.  Any hints?

My Emacs is Emacs 23.3.1 (x86_64-apple-darwin, NS apple-appkit-1038.35).

Answer (score 10):

Put this in your Emacs init file:

```
(global-set-key '[(kp-delete)] 'delete-char)
```

You might also need to add the following:

```
(global-set-key '[(delete)] 'delete-char)
(global-set-key '[(meta delete)] 'kill-word)
(global-set-key '[(meta kp-delete)] 'kill-word)
(global-set-key '[(control delete)] 'kill-word)
(global-set-key '[(control kp-delete)] 'kill-word)
```

Comment: Glad it did the job for you. You could accept the answer if you're satisfied with it in order to flag it as being answered.

Answer (score 0):

Try M-x global-set-key RET key forward-delete -- if it works, try M-x repeat-complex-command but instead of reissuing the command, copy and paste it into your .emacs file.